# Why connecting omni 10 speakers with bluetooth results in lower quality sound?

Tags: bluetooth

I am connecting omni 10 speakers with my computer's bluetooth.

This is what I see

[image]

As you can see from the picture. It has only 16 bit 44k hz sound and I can't change that.

My regular hdmi has higher specs

[image]

Harman Kardon websites claim that their spec is

http://www.harmankardon.com/wifi-speakers/OMNI+10.html

> Unlike other wireless streaming systems, the Harman Kardon Omni
>   10supports 24bit / 96kHz Studio Quality HD audio streaming. Enjoy a
>   superior audio experience, higher resolution than from a CD

Comment: Lower sound quality compared to what? Describe a little bit more, what you mean by lower quality as well. And: do other bluetooth speakers provide better quality?

Comment: lower than harman kardon's own spec in their websites

Comment: I think it's a limitation of bluetooth. You would probably need to playback via WiFi to get the maximum quality.